# Send Excel file to customer with OLAP connection

Tags: excel, ssas, olap

Is there a way to send an Excel file with OLAP (SSAS) data to a client and hide the OLAP fieldlist?

We tried to copy/paste the data to another Excel file but we loose the layout by doing this.

Maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your question confusing.  I presume you mean to remove the connection.

I would go to the Data ribbon and choose Connections, then select the Connection object for your SSAS cube and choose Remove.